# Setting the mutual point of a laptop and external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a laptop (1) and an extenal monitor (2) connected to it. The laptop is 1280x800 and the external one 1920x1080 resolution. The both stand on the desk, and the (2) is, due to its stand, some 10 cm above the laptop.

When using both monitors together, their mutual point is in the upper right corner of (1) or upper left of the (2).

However, that means that when I'm scrolling the mouse from one to the other, if I go from the (1) to (2), by means of upper right corner, that mouse cursor will show on the top of (2). I'm sure you're getting the point by now.

I am using Windows XP SP3.

***How to set the monitors together, so one can take their physical position/placement into account, so that when one scrolls from one to the other, the cursor appears at the same height?***

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Just drag the thumbnails around in the display properties settings?  I'm not seeing the problem here.

Comment: @Shinrai - think of the situation; draw the cursor between two same monitors except one is 10cm above the other.

Comment: @Rook - Right.  So drag one about that much up?

Comment: @Shinrai - Half my desktop goes missing then ... (icons on the top of the desktop are inaccessible) ... windows still thinks the desktop starts where it starts.

Comment: @Rook - Do you have these just on normal extended desktop? That's not normal behavior.  Can you be more specific about the exact video card and how these monitors are configured?  (If this is in span mode there is no way to get the behavior you want, period.)

Comment: @Shinrai - I have them on "extend my desktop" mode. I don't know about "span mode".

Comment: @shinrai - Sorry, I spoke too soon. After an unplanned restart, everything felt into its place. Now it works as it should (don't know what the glitch was). If you want, put this ... anything, as an answer and I'll accept it. In any case, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Rook - Nah, it's okay, I have plenty of rep.  You should answer and accept your own so it doesn't stay open though.  (That's weird behavior, too, I've never seen it just bug out like that...I was confused because you seem savvy enough to understand how that interface works.  Obviously you do!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, goes like this:

Right click on Desktop/Properties/Settings/Move the (2) monitor "thingie" up or down, until you get it just right. If your desktop icons seem to be missing, restart Windows. That seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Place a window so it is across the two monitors, showing on both. This way you can see exactly how it will line up without having to guage based on the mouse moving between the two.